Relative algebraic $K$ theory of Galois extensions
Let $R$ be a domain, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $R\to R[x]/I$ be an integral extension, e.g $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
Is anything known about the relative algebraic $K$ groups, $K_*(R',R)$? For example, when $R\to R'$ is a nilpotent extension, the Dennis trace map from relative $K$ theory to relative negative cyclic homology is an isomorphism.
Is there a similar "simpler" spectrum that computes the relative $K$-theory of a quadratic extension?

I am not sure whether it is easy to compare the algebraic K-theories of real numbers and of complex numbers.

Let me mention that comparing $K_0$ should already be nontrivial: it is a direct sum of $\mathbb Z$ and the class group, and an easy control of $K_0$ should lead to, say, a simple proof of the Stark–Heegner theorem.
